# Weird behaviour with hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, hash

I have a method that tries to parse a query into a a hash.

```
CONTACT_SEARCH_FIELDS = ['LastUpdate','Name','RecAdd','PhoneNumber','Tag_Group','FirstName','LastName','FamilyName','FamilyHead','ClientStatus','ContactType','ClientSource','TaxId']
CONTACT_SEARCH_OPERANDS = ['=','>','<','!=','Like','BeginsWith','IsEmpty']

def search (query, page = 1)
    body = [{}]*query.length
    query.each_with_index do |expr, i|
        body[i]["Field"] = CONTACT_SEARCH_FIELDS.index expr[0]
        body[i]["Operand"] = CONTACT_SEARCH_OPERANDS.index expr[1]
        body[i]["Value"] = expr[2]
    end
    return body
end
```

The method is called like this

```
search([["FirstName", "=", "John"], ["LastName", "=", "Smith"]])
```

The problem is that running this gives a very weird output.

```
search([["FirstName", "=", "John"], ["LastName", "=", "Smith"]])
=> [{"Operand"=>0, "Value"=>"Smith", "Field"=>6}, {"Operand"=>0, "Value"=>"Smith", "Field"=>6}]
```

I did some debugging and the problem is that all the hashes in the array are get set on every iteration.

I dont understand what is the reason behind this. I would also welcome any shorter or better versions of this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the line

```
body = [{}]*query.length
```

The above means, you are creating an *Array*, whose elements are same `Hash` objects.

Example :

```
a = [{}]*3 # => [{}, {}, {}]
a.map(&:object_id) # => [18499356, 18499356, 18499356]
a[0]["a"] = 2
a # => [{"a"=>2}, {"a"=>2}, {"a"=>2}]
```

to

```
body = Array.new(query.length) { {} }
```

But the above means, you are creating an *Array*,  whose elements are different `Hash` objects.

Example :

```
a = Array.new(3) { {} } # => [{}, {}, {}]
a.map(&:object_id) # => [17643864, 17643852, 17643840]
a[0]["a"] = 2
a # => [{"a"=>2}, {}, {}]
```

Comment: Does the first definition create n hashes which point to the same address in memory?